# PHP one method for both static and instanciated scope

Tags: php, static

While creating a PHP helper method, I am trying to find an elegant way to have the same method available for both static calls and instanciated calls, while still being able to access the instance when called from the instance call.

Consider `getModelName()` method within an `Entity` class:

```
 public static function getModelName($entity) {

       if (is_string($entity)) {

            $entity =  ///query to return an entity object;

            return !empty($entity) ? $entity->model : false;

        }

        if (is_a($entity, "\namespace\path\Entity")) {

            return $entity->model;

        }

       return false;
}
```

Since different classes across the application use this method, and some of them already have an instance of $entity, I want to be able to call it directly so I don't need to pass an instance of $entity as an argument every time:

```
$entity->getModelName();
```

The method itself need to be able to do:

```
public static function getModelName($entity = null) {

           if (is_string($entity)) {

                $entity =  ///query to return an entity object;

                return !empty($entity) ? $entity->model : false;

            }

           if (empty($entity)) {
               //this is where it fails of course since $this is not available
               //in a static method
               return $this->model;
           } 

           return false;
        }
```

This solution obviously fails since $this is not available within a static method.
Any ideas how to solve this predicament without having 2 different methods?

Thanks for the help!

**UPDATE**
I am using Laravel so $entity is a database ORM model (Eloquent). I didn't think it's relevant originally because this is a general question about PHP method scopes. After reading the comments I see it's important to mention. Instanciaing a new $entity is only an option if I have to since it will query the database.

Comment: Why can't you simply make your $model property static as well as the method?

Comment: Can't use self::model?

Comment: @EasyBB No since `$model` is not static

Comment: Gotcha I just don't see where he creates model anywhere lol

Comment: @EasyBB $entity->model is actually a database column that is being retrieved when $entity is being instanciated.

Comment: @MarkBaker $entity->model is a being retrieved from the database. Please see the update to the question. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no way to access `$this` inside static methods, you should look at this problem from a different angle.

Simply put, `$this` is an instance of the current class, therefore you need to instantiate it and then access its properties or methods. So you can handle it like this:

```
if (empty($entity)) {
   $instance = new self();
   return $instance->model;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the question, basically I'm using Laravel's Eloquent ORM so $entity is not a simple object that I can instanciate without re-querying the database.